# Smith normal form and affine buildings

Tags: reference-request, matrices, buildings, smith-normal-form

In [Smith Normal Form of powers of a matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131373/smith-normal-form-of-powers-of-a-matrix) someone has commented saying that one can reformulate many questions about Smith normal forms in the language of affine buildings. I wanted to know of a reference for this link or an explanation of how they are related.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in:

*Shemanske, Thomas R.*, [**The arithmetic and combinatorics of buildings for $\text{Sp}_n$.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-07-04293-6), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 359, No. 7, 3409-3423 (2007). [ZBL1126.20019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1126.20019).

(see section 4).